# Images produced by Inkscape display incorrectly in pdflatex document

Tags: pdf, latex, inkscape

I have some problems with images I created with Inkscape  (processed by pdflatex).

I produced a book which I'm trying to publish by CreateSpace.

The images in the proof of the document produced by CreateSpace  appear to be altered in the print: some characters are moved around randomly, sometimes two characters have switched locations within the same image.

This may have something to do with transparencies of some images which have been flattened during the pre-processing of the pdf file I submitted to CreateSpace.

Is there a way to flatten transparency with Inkscape or other software on Linux?

Thank you.

Comment: How did you embed your images into your LaTeX document? What format are the images in? SVG, pdf or png?

Comment: I have never used CreateSpace, but I have had issues in the past with SVG images, from different origins. PDF readers like Evince are not able to portrait them correctly - these are usually issues with the reader, not with the image. In such cases I try to use a pixelised version.